# Silverlight {Binding Key} - Please refresh my memory?

Tags: silverlight, binding

I'm sure this is simple, but what the hell am I missing here? Can someone tell me what the keyword "Key" is referencing in `Text="{Binding Key}"`? I know I learned about it previously, but I cannot seem to remember. I understand how databinding works, just stuck on this particular issue.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="groupItemHeader">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                    Width="432" Height="62"
                    Margin="6" Padding="12,0,0,6">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" 
                           Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontSize="26.667"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
                <Border.Projection>
                    <PlaneProjection RotationX="-60"/>
                </Border.Projection>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{Binding Key}` is shorthand for `{Binding Path=Key}`.  This will return the value of the `Key` property on the current `DataContext`.

Comment: So "Key" would definitely have to be a property of the source object of the binding?

Comment: No, the `Source` has not been specified on the `Binding`.  The `DataContext` in this case is the object that the `DataTemplate` is being used for, so the `Key` property must appear on that